# Application interrupted when DataTable.Load(), where is the issue?

Tags: c#, t-sql, datatable

I'm doing a C# Windows Forms Application that downloads files from an API, unzip those files and parse them into the database. **My problem is at the parsing part.** And other threads about "*The application in break mode*" do not clarify why this happen with `.Load()`.

I do an Openrowset query to read the file in the database. It reads everything fine. Then I do a `dataTable.Load()` of that reader. **Then the application is stopped by an internal exception thrown inside that library. It just interrupts. I don't get information about the exception.** Here is the essential part of the code (the real query is so long, I put this one as an example):

```
private DataTable dataTable;
    public void loadDataTable()
    {
        dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTableConsumo.Load(queryExecutor.ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM Prices", connection));
    }

    public SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(String query, SqlConnection connection)
    {
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        comando.CommandTimeout = 0;
        return comando.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

**The CSV file is huge. It has 17 million rows.** **I tried to load the file doing a top 200000 and it works fine** when I `.Load()` and then `.WriteToServer` (doing a new Instance to the DataTable and forcing the GC call at every iteration of the partitioned loop based on total rows), but only 2-3 times. At the fourth load, it just stops. And it's not about memory because I'm controlling it all the time. I tried many things. Some screenshots:

[image: First iteration]

[image: Second iteration (check the arrow)]

And the non-helping message that gives me nightmares and doesn't let me see the exception or even debug the code:

[image: The message]

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems like it's a Visual Studio bug. It happens in WinForms applications and **it is not critical. The application just stops, but you can resume it again and it works fine.**

If you port the WinForms application to an automated console application, this never happens. Problem partially solved.